# Not Found page odoo 16

Tags: postgresql, odoo, pgadmin-4

## What I use

My `os` is `windows 11` and my ide that I use is `pycharm` and I installed `odoo version 16` from github

I was trying to configure **Odoo** on windows 11 and I made it work *but* then suddenly when I closed `pycharm` It stopped working and keep in mind I didn't close `pgAdmin`

so This Error keeps popping up when I type in my Browser `localhost:8069`

## Error

The Error is:

```
Not Found
The requested URL was not found on the server. If you entered the URL manually please check your spelling and try again.
```

and in the terminal :

```
  File "C:\Users\Eng.Ehab\Downloads\odoo\odoo\addons\web\controllers\database.py", line 19, in <module>
    from odoo.addons.base.models.ir_qweb import render as qweb_render
  File "C:\Users\Eng.Ehab\Downloads\odoo\odoo\odoo\addons\base\__init__.py", line 5, in <module>
    from . import models
  File "C:\Users\Eng.Ehab\Downloads\odoo\odoo\odoo\addons\base\models\__init__.py", line 21, in <module>
    from . import ir_mail_server
  File "C:\Users\Eng.Ehab\Downloads\odoo\odoo\odoo\addons\base\models\ir_mail_server.py", line 14, in <module>
    import ssl
  File "D:\paython\lib\ssl.py", line 98, in <module>
    import _ssl             # if we can't import it, let the error propagate
ImportError: DLL load failed while importing _ssl: The specified module could not be found.
2023-09-06 09:51:17,042 15532 INFO ? odoo.service.server: HTTP service (werkzeug) running on LAPTOP-32D379NK:8069 
2023-09-06 09:51:22,368 15532 INFO ? werkzeug: 127.0.0.1 - - [06/Sep/2023 09:51:22] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 404 - 1 0.007 0.070
```

and the `odoo.conf` file code:

```
[options]
; This is the password that allows database operations:
admin_passwd = Admin
db_host = localhost
db_port = 5433
db_user = odoo-16
db_password = Admin
addons_path = C:\Users\Eng.Ehab\Downloads\odoo\odoo\addons

http_port = 8069
```

and If you need more data tell me and I will give it to you right away

I tried to create a new database and a new user in `postgresql`

> Keep In Mind I am not a pro at it I actually don't know `postgres`

Comment: Looks more like a python issue.  What version of Python do you use?  Interesting path name for python "d:\paython"?    If it isn't python...  what is it?

Comment: I use python version 3.8 and I really don't know what this path is but when I checked it. turns out it was the installation for python 3.8 If you need more info tell me and thanks for trying to help me

Answer (score -2):

Try following these steps to fix the "ImportError;

Install OpenSSL and add its directory to the system PATH.

Make sure the Python version you're using is compatible with Odoo 16.

Verify that all of Odoo's dependencies have been correctly installed.

Examine and modify the settings for your PostgreSQL database.

To apply modifications, restart the Odoo service.

```
odoo-bin -c odoo.conf
```

Check to see whether your antivirus or firewall program is preventing Odoo.

For more detailed error information, keep an eye on the Odoo logs.

Consider choosing a Linux-based environment for a potentially smoother experience because Odoo frequently performs better on Linux platforms.